# How to use up() in Ext.Button handler

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

**Back Ground** : I am working on an MVC application using sencha touch 2. I am working on a page which has two tabs. Inside the first tab, I have a button inside a title bar.

**Issue** :  I am not able to call anyother function from the button handler. I think, there is an issue with the scope of the calling function.

Here is my code.

```
Ext.define('WUPOC.view.WUHomePage', {
  extend: 'Ext.TabPanel',
  requires:['Ext.TitleBar','Ext.dataview.List','Ext.data.proxy.JsonP'],
  alias: 'widget.wuHomePageView',

  config: {
    fullscreen: true,

    defaults: {
      styleHtmlContent: true
    },

    items: [{
      title: 'Home',
      iconCls: 'home',

      items: [{
        xtype: 'titlebar',
        title: 'Hello',
        docked: 'top',
        items: [{
          xtype: 'button',
          text: 'LogOut',
          ui: 'action',
          itemId: 'newButton',
          align: 'right',
          handler : function(btn){
            console.log('LogOut is tapped');  // This is printed
            this.up.onNewButtonTap();  // Throws error
          }
        }],
      }],
    }, {
      title: 'Contact',
      iconCls: 'user',
      html: 'Contact Screen'
    }]
  },

  onNewButtonTap: function () {
    alert('newNoteCommand');
  },
});
```

I am getting the error as below.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (selector) {
        var result = this.parent;

        if (selector) {
            for (; result; result = result.parent) {
                if (Ext.ComponentQuery.is(result, selector)) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    } has no method 'onNewButtonTap'
```

I think there is an issue with setting the scope of a button. Kindly help.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `up` is a function so you need to call it this way :

```
this.up();
```

Then `this.up()` would only bring to the container of the button, which has no method `onNewButtonTap`. You could just keep doing up() until you get the right component but this would me more clever to do :

- Add an xtype to your view
- Use this xtype as a selector in the up function : `this.up('myXType').onNewButtonTap();`

[Example](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#UT18y)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot TDeBailleul for the sollution. Your explanation was very helpful.

Comment: Hi  TDeBailleul,I have one more doubt. If I try to do same with list what i tried with button then it does not work. I mean when I try to associate tap Handler or disclose handler with list, i am not able to get the log on my console that list is clicked.Working example is at http://www.senchafiddle.com/#tmTjb . Kindly help

Comment: That's because Ext.List doesn't have the handler config like Ext.Button (http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List). Take a look a the listeners config instead (here's an example http://try.sencha.com/touch/2.0.1/guides/list.1/)

Comment: Thanks TDeBailleul. I am new bee to sencha so some stupid questions arises. Thanks a lot for helping. :)