# How to use this.up() function in button handler in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I have looked into this question, but this does not solve my problem
[How to use up() in Ext.Button handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868699/how-to-use-up-in-ext-button-handler)

I am trying to implement a simple button handler, and want to handle of a Panel's toolbar's button. I am defining a onNewFeed3 function in the panel, not sure how to call that when the button's tap event is clicked. I don't want to use a separate controller class, but want it all in the View class.  The above link seems to answer this, I am still getting the two errors as I mention down below in the code.

The reason for the first code after the first comment was to ascertain the XType of "this", and I am not sure what's the best way to do this, as I am getting a TypeError

Thanks

```
Ext.define('Volt.view.FeedView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',

    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'Ext.Button',
        'Ext.Toolbar'
        //'Ext.Panel'
    ],

    xtype: 'feedViewCard',



    config: {
        iconCls: 'action',
        title: 'FeedView',

        layout: {
            type: 'vbox'
        },

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                title: 'Home',
                docked: 'top',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'spacer'

                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'New2 Feed',
                        ui: 'action',
                        id: 'new_note_button',

/*  I HAVE TRIED THIS AND DOES NOT WORK - GIVES TypeError : undefined is not a function */
                        handler: function(){
                            console.log('button tapped inline handler, xtype =');
                            console.log(this.getXTypes());

                        },

/*  and this gives the same error as well : TypeError : undefined is not a function*/
                        handler: this.up('feedViewCard').onNewFeed3,

                        scope: this
                    }

                ]

            }
        ]
    },

    onNewFeed3: function(){
        console.log('New Feed 3 button clicked');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your handler does not run in the scope of button, therefore errors as `this` points to the global scope (window). Button handler receives the button clicked as the first argument so the handler should read:

```
handler:function(btn) {
    btn.up('feedViewCard').onNewFeed3();
}
```

Comment: Thanks this code with (btn) and using btn.up() worked, but not the code from "sha" above, using this. I am not sure where the "this" in the handler:function(){ } points to - surely it should point to the button right? How can I print to console the XType or some identifying properties like title of the "this"? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change it to something like that (that didn't work because handler is being executed in the scope of view already and this is not pointed to the button):

```
handler: function() {
    this.up('feedViewCard').onNewFeed3();
}
```

You can always debug the scope of the function using

```
console.log(this)
```

And if the handler by default is being executed in the scope of the view itself you don't need any lookup function at all. Change the handler to:

```
handler: function() {
    this.onNewFeed3();
}
```

Comment: I checked this out. Pls see comment on the answer from @saki